# How to add prompt to Langchain ConversationalRetrievalChain chat over docs with history?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain

Langchain have added this function `ConversationalRetrievalChain` which is used to chat over docs with history. According to their documentation here [ConversationalRetrievalChain](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/chat_vector_db.html#get-chat-history-function) I need to pass prompts which are instructions to the function. How can i achieve that with this function call?

here is the code

```
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0), vectorstore.as_retriever(), memory=memory)
```

Comment: Why did you delete your answer? isnt it working? Do you have an answer to  your own question that works?

Answer (score 15):

You can pass your prompt in `ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm()` method with the `combine_docs_chain_kwargs` param. See the below example with ref to your provided sample code:

```py
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=OpenAI(temperature=0),
    retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt}
)
```

If you see the source, the `combine_docs_chain_kwargs` then pass through the `load_qa_chain()` with your provided prompt.

Comment: finally found this. worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

this code worked for me (Thanks to [DennisPeeters](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/5462)) :

````py
general_system_template = r""" 
Given a specific context, please give a short answer to the question, covering the required advices in general and then provide the names all of relevant(even if it relates a bit) products. 
 ----
{context}
----
"""
general_user_template = "Question:```{question}```"
messages = [
            SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(general_system_template),
            HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(general_user_template)
]
qa_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages( messages )

return ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
            llm=ChatOpenAI(
                model_name=self.model_name,
                temperature=self.temperature,
                max_tokens=self.max_tokens,
            ),
            retriever=self.retriever,
            chain_type="stuff",
            verbose=self.verbose,
            , combine_docs_chain_kwargs={'prompt': qa_prompt}
        )
````

Comment: Hi, I used your code and it works perfect, thanks! But i want to add memory to the conversation (=chat history). How do i do that?

Comment: Hi @Nat. You can use ConversationBufferMemory with chat_memory set to e.g. SQLChatMessageHistory (or Redis like I am using). E.g.:

```
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
    chat_memory=RedisChatMessageHistory(
        session_id=conversation_id,
        url=redis_url,
        key_prefix="your_redis_index_prefix"
    ),
    memory_key="chat_history",
    return_messages=True
)
´´´

You can e.g. use SQLite instead for testing locally with SQL DB, or you can even do the testing with in memory history but this won't scale to multiple users as it requires a session_id.

Comment: Hi, I'm running the code with streamlit. So i need to save the chat in session state and then pass it to the ConversationalRetrievalChain somehow. I got stuck there..

Comment: With this solution I can only set chain_type to stuff, e.g., map_reduce will not work. Why?